# Using Abstract class as a parameter and making new Items of that class

Tags: c#, function, class, inheritance, abstract

I have 2 APIs which both have the same methods but with different names.

I made an abstract class inherited from this with both of them.

Now I am trying to make another class which uses those APIs and I don't want it to care which API it uses.

How do I pass the abstract class as a parameter and use it as one of the api's?

Is there a better way to do it?

Example Code :

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract string Func1();

}
public class Class1: AbstractClass
{
    public override string Func1()
    {
        return "Class1";
    }

}
public abstract class Class2: AbstractClass
{
    public override string Func1()
    {
        return "Class2";
    }

}
public class Class3
{
    Type type;
    public Class3(Type type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public string UseFunc1()
    {
        //I know this wont work but what shuld I do
        type a = new type();
        return a.Func1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: Added example code

Comment: Well you _could_ use `Activator.CreateInstance` but having a factory would be more type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be trying to achieve is the below. While you can't create an abstract class you can pass one

```
public class Class3
{
    AbstractClass abstractMember

    public Class3(AbstractClass abstractMember)
    {
       this.abstractMember = abstractMember;
    }

    public string UseFunc1()
    {
        return abstractMember.Func1();
    }
}
```

You'd call it like:

```
Class2 c2 = new Class2();
Class3 c3 = new Class3(c2);
```